# Can I override a query in DJango?

Tags: python, django

I know you can override delete and save methods in DJango models, but can you override a select query somehow to intercept and change a parameter slightly.  I have a hashed value I want to check for, and would like to keep the hashing internal to the model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't make it absolutely clear what you want to do, but I think there are two possibilities here.

The general way to override the database query is to define a [custom Manager](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/db/managers/), and override `get_query_set` method. You can add extra filtering criteria here.

However, if I understand your question properly, you are trying to change the query for a particular field only. In this case, I think the better answer is to define a [custom Field](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/howto/custom-model-fields/). Here you can [override `get_db_prep_lookup`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/howto/custom-model-fields/#preparing-values-for-use-in-database-lookups) which allows you to customise the value that is used in the database lookup.

Comment: Perfect, you nailed it.  Essentially I have passwords I have to hash and store, and I wanted the model to handle all hashing during saves and updates, and to hash the password it is passed when validating the user.  I think DJango models and admin could use a hashed field type.

Answer (score 1):

if you're using 1.2, you can try [raw()](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/), which seems like exactly what you're looking for.